# Datatable Jquery displays an error, informing that the request was not made safely, using HTTPS

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-core, datatable

In my ASP.NET core MVC application, I am using Identity. The curious thing is that, even though it is authenticated and with the correct permissions, the datatable displays an error, informing that the request was not made safely, using HTTPS. What do I do to fix this?

Thanks :)

```
var table = dataTableObj.DataTable({
    "select": true,
    "processing": false,
    "serverSide": true,
    "filter": true,
    "orderMulti": false,
    "ordering": true,
    "order": [[1, "asc"]],
    "ajax": {
        "url": '/servico-web-gerenciar/getServicoWeb',
        "type": "POST",
        "datatype": "json",
        "error": function (e) {
            stopLoadGlobal();

            redirectToError(e.status);

            return false;
        }
    }
});

[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
[Route("servico-web-gerenciar/getServicoWeb")]
public JsonResult GetServicoWeb()
{
    var draw = Request.Form["draw"];
    var start = Request.Form["start"];
    var length = Request.Form["length"];

    var search = Request.Form["search[value]"];

    int pageSize = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(length) ? Convert.ToInt32(length) : 0;
    int skip = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(start) ? Convert.ToInt32(start) : 0;
    int totalRecords = 0;
    int recordsFiltered = 0;

    var documentoTipo = _servicoWebAppService.GetPaginated(search, skip, pageSize, out totalRecords, out recordsFiltered, true);

    return Json(new
    {
        draw = draw,
        recordsFiltered = recordsFiltered,
        recordsTotal = totalRecords,
        data = documentoTipo,
    });
}
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HY9n7.png)

Comment: just find your static resources (css, js, ...) linked in your view files and change `http` to `https`.

Comment: Please do not use screenshots of text. Add the (formatted) text to the question, instead. See [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://localhost:44373/xxxx' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

You can check this doc to know more about "mixed content blocking":

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content

To fix it, all requests to HTTP content should be removed and replaced with content served over HTTPS.

And I find that the source you are accessing is also available over HTTPS, you can try to load it over HTTPS, like below.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono" />
```

Comment: Thank you @Fei Han!! :)